# How To Backup A Maintenance Plan

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005, export, maintenance, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2005, and I'm about to make changes to the (rather important) Maintenance Plan. I would like to backup (or export) the Maintenance Plan, so it can be restored (or imported) in case the changes made cause any problems.

My Question Is: How can this be done?

I've looked online, and found some people talking about using Integration Services to perform this task. Unfortunately, I do not see an Integration Services utility on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3066351/Migrating-a-Maintenance-Plan-from-One-SQL-Server-to-Another.htm) discusses the steps for migrating a maintenance plan from one server to another.  I believe you can use the same procedure to backup your plan before making a change.

Comment: This is the route I ended up taking. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in SQL Server 2005 maintenance plans are created as SSIS packages and always stored in MSDB.  As long as you're backing up MSDB you'll have your maintenance plan backup.